# Notation for unevenly-spaced to evenly-spaced time series conversion

Tags: time-series, notation, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have an unevenly-spaced time series. To make it evenly-spaced, I resample the time series to a larger timespan (e.g. day) and sum up all values within this time frame.

In Python (and pandas) it is a one-liner:

```py
ts.resample('D').sum()
```

But what is a precise (and ideally easily unterstandable) mathematical notation for that?

Comment: It all depends on exactly how "resample" works!  There can't be a mathematical notation for a vaguely defined operation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. `resample('MS').sum()` sums up all values within a calendar month. Independent from the timespan (one month), I would like to express exactly this. Probably my Python example is not helpful?

Comment: It's helpful insofar as it uncovers potential complications.  For instance, a monthly series is not actually evenly spaced in terms of physical time: it is only evenly spaced relative to a social construct concerning how we represent time on a human scale.  This suggests that something well beyond a mathematical operator is needed to express what Python is doing--but is that really what you're after?

Comment: Good point - months are a really bad example. I changed it to days. Then it should be evenly-spaced time series. I actually would prefer a mathematical notion over some Python/pseudo code.

Comment: Where is `ts` coming from? It might be very clear to you, however, I'm an infrequent Python user and don't know what you imported there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Let's start with a generalization.**  Suppose the original data are a series of values $\mathbf{x}=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ associated with times $\mathbf{t}=(t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n).$  You have in mind a new set of ordered times indexed by the integers $\mathbf Z$ along with a function $f(k, \mathbf{t}, \mathbf{x})$ that determines what new value to assign to the integer $k$ based on the data in $(\mathbf{t}, \mathbf{x}).$  The new time series is just

$$(y_k) = (f(k, \mathbf{t}, \mathbf{x})),\ k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

**In the example in the question,** you have partitioned an interval of time from $t_0$ to $t_\infty \gt t_0$ into (say) $N$ evenly spaced intervals, each of which therefore has a length $$h= (t_\infty - t_0)/N,$$ and I am presuming (as is conventional) that you wish to index them with the integers $0, 1, 2, \ldots, N-1.$  The interval in which any time $t$ lies therefore is

$$g(t) = \lfloor \frac{t-t_0}{h} \rfloor.$$

Your resampling function sums all values within each interval and therefore can be written

$$f(k,\mathbf{t},\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{\{i\,\mid\, g(t_i)=k\}}x_i.$$

(Empty sums are, by definition, zero.)

If you like, you may combine these formulas in one grand (but less immediate) one,

> $$y_k =  \sum_{\{i\,\mid\, \lfloor N\frac{t_i-t_0}{t_\infty-t_0} \rfloor=k\}}x_i.$$

To demonstrate how *non* abstract and natural this is, here is an `R` implementation of the last formula:

```R
function(times, x, t.0, t.infty, N) tapply(x, floor(N * (times - t.0)/(t.infty - t.0)), sum)
```

It returns an array indexed by the new times with values equal to the sums within each new interval.